# Html2Canvas: take screenshot of "Hello"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, screenshot

Trying to figure out why this is not working, it should take a screenshot of "Hello" onload but isn't doing anything?

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="html2canvas.js">
  window.onload = function(){
    html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    },
width: 300,
height: 300
})};
</script>
</body>
<h1>Hello</h1>

<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid      #d3d3d3;">

</html>
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation - http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html - I take it you do have **html2canvas.js** in the same directory as that piece of HTML ... p.s. you don't need to create a canvas, the html2canvas function returns one for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <html>
<body>
<script src="html2canvas.js">
  window.onload = function(){
    html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    },
width: 300,
height: 300
})};
</script>
<h1>Hello</h1>

<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid      #d3d3d3;">
</body>


</html>
```

Move your canvas and h1 tags within the `<body>` and `</body>` tags.

Comment: I am still getting a blank canvas? @Ricky